# bootstrap vertical align in mobile mode

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have created this [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/niqajog/edit?html,output) that shows the problem and below is the markup:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4 xs-12">
    <strong>UK Postcode</strong>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 xs-12">
    <strong>Other Field</strong>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-3 xs-12">
    <input class="form-input"/>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-1 xs-12">
    <strong>Or</strong>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3 xs-12">
    <input class="form-input"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

In the bin the elements are aligned correctly in every mode but mobile.

In mobile mode I want them to stack up vertically but I am not sure how to get the `other field` label to appear below the `Or` label and above the correct input in mobile mode.

Currently it looks like this in mobile mode:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your HTML to this along with some bootstrap's default classes.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
      <label><strong>UK Postcode</strong></label>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-1">
      <div class="invisible hidden-xs">
        &nbsp;
        <!-- Just to give similar white space above OR text but as well hide this gap in mobile devices. -->
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <strong>OR</strong>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
      <label><strong>Other Field</strong></label>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2e01v8xx/)
you can try something like this.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-3 xs-12">
    <label class="labels" for="fm1">UK Postcode</label>
    <input class="form-input"/ id="fm1">
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-1 xs-12">
    <strong>Or</strong>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3 xs-12">
  <label class="labels" for="fm2">Other Field</label>
    <input class="form-input" id="fm2">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you know how I can get the <strong>Or</strong> to be aligned with the inputs when in horizontal mode?